# Is there a way with kafka-node to request a received messages after a crash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I been looking at the docks and now wondering if this is even a feature of kafka or node-kafka.

So my consumer receives a message from kafka, and while I process the message, I like to mark it as if I didn't get it until I completed processing it. This way, if the server crashes while processing, I can reconnect and received the messages that my application received prior to the crash it was working on.

High level example.

1. Kafka message is a user id;
2. Once received, I get user info from the database.
3. I send an email to the user.
4. When the email is sent. I log it to the database.
5. I mark message complete. (I'm not sure if this step is possible)

This way, if any of the steps crashes before step five, when the server is back up, it receives the failed message again.

I'm using node.js `LTS 8.10.0` and the npm package `kafka-node@2.4.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to save your last read offset to a database that you prefer. This way you can use this offset to start your consumer from the next time you restart it.

Kafka provides a mechanism to do this inbuilt with versions `> 0.8`. Kafka stores the latest offset read by a consumer group to an internal topic called `consumer_offsets`. Most of the client libraries have a provision to auto-commit last processed offset or you may opt to disable auto-commit and commit the offset yourself once your entire processing is complete.

Comment: So using the consumer_offsets, I was able to get the latest offset without needing a database. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I gave credit to void because his answer helped me find what I needed in kafka-node. Here is just the node.js answer/example.

```
const kafkaConfig = config.get('kafka');
const kafkaClient = new kafka.KafkaClient({kafkaHost: kafkaConfig.host});
const consumer = new kafka.Consumer(kafkaClient, [{topic: kafkaConfig.topic}], {autoCommit: false});
const offset = new kafka.Offset(kafkaClient);

// very import to retrieve the offset
offset.fetchLatestOffsets([kafkaConfig.topic], (error, offsets) => {
    const latestOffset = offsets[kafkaConfig.topic][0];
    consumer.setOffset(kafkaConfig.topic, 0, latestOffset);
});

consumer.on('message', message => {
    // do stuff
    Log.insert({message})
        .then(() => {
            // commit the success so that kafka will update the offset
            consumer.commit((err, data) => console.log(err, data));
        })
});
```